# How to update AWS credentials in Elastic Beanstalk environment variables when changing IAM user keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk-js

How do I update the IAM security credentials in the environmental variables in an Elastic Beanstalk application?

In my application I'm getting the following error sending a message to the AWS SQS queue.  `403 (Forbidden)
bundle.js:27819 Error: The security token included in the request is invalid.`

I changed my IAM credentials so I'm assuming I need to update the  environmental variables in my Elastic Beanstalk application, and I'm assuming this is the reason for the above error.

I tried to update the security credentials in the environmental variables in my Elastic Beanstalk application by running `aws configure`. If I'm understanding correctly it has updated the credentials file in my .aws folder. But I don't think it updated the security credentials in the environmental variables in my AWS Elastic Beanstalk application. How to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I tried to update the security credentials in the environmental variables in my Elastic Beanstalk application by running aws configure*.

That is incorrect assumption, `aws configure` updates only `.aws` contents, which has nothing to do with ElasticBeanstalk environment variables.

If you need to update EB environment variables, then you need to use this command

```
eb setenv key=value
```

BUT, and this is a huge but, never store your credentials in a place such as remote instance. That is not how you are supposed to give permissions to your applications. Of course you can do that using environment variables but that is a huge security risk. You should create appropriate role and attach it to your EB environment instead. That way you don't need to manage your credentials and give your application all the permission it needs.

Comment: Thank you @Matus . Can you explain what you mean about creating an appropriate `role` to store the `security credentials`? My understanding is that `roles` are presets to be selected, rather than somewhere `security credentials` can be stored. How do you store `security credentials` in `roles`?

Comment: @AgentZebra Let's say that you want your user to have access rights to S3. How do you achieve this? You create IAM policy that allows that and and attach it to that user (or group of which the users is part of). Security credentials are used only to identify the user, not to give them access rights. Those are given via IAM policies. Now, instead of user you can create a role with the same IAM policy. Any service that assumes that role will have the same rights as the above mentioned user. It is the underlying IAM policy that matters, not a user or a role.

Comment: Thanks Matus, ah I get it! For some reason SQS is not on the list of options to select after clicking on `Roles` and `Create Role` - surely it's there I need to select SQS? Or should I be selecting EBS there? If SQS is not available as an option to create a role for, what do we do in this case? (The error is happening when trying to connect to SQS from EBS. My group my user is attached to already has full SQS access).

Comment: @AgentZebra When you create EB environment, there should be instance profile created with it (something like `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role`) under roles, which is attached to your ec2 instances running in EB environment. You can modify this role and add something like `AmazonSQSFullAccess` permission to it. While this will work, you should be more granular and tighten the above mentioned permission to only to specific resources that your EB EC2 instances need.